# Separating authentication and authorization in a legacy system, using LDAP and Java EE

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, kerberos, saml

I have a legacy custom "ID hub" which holds authentication and authorization data in an internal relational database - no LDAP, ActiveDirectory or the like. The "ID hub" exposes custom legacy APIs which operate using custom "login tokens" - a successful call to the login operation returns a token that is reused for retrieving authorization information, etc.

I am redesigning the "ID hub" so that its authentication data can be extracted into a proper directory, which offers an LDAP interface. Given that the username will be the "key" to matching authentication and authorization entries, I believe the interfaces of the ID hub can be kept unchanged, while the implementation is adapted, incl. the access from ID hub to the authentication directory. As my applications rely on the ID hub, the legacy interfaces of the ID hub cannot be retired yet.

My problem is: in a second step, I also need to modernize the ID hub so that the roles are switched: the applications would access the aforementioned directory which would no longer be authentication-only, but would now also expose authorization interfaces (e.g. again using LDAP) and serve as the entrypoint, instead of the "ID hub". It is important that at the same time, the authorization data is kept in the legacy "ID hub".

My question is: how can I make the "ID hub" callable from that directory in a trusted way, i.e. how can I solve the problem that the "ID hub" need trusted information from the "frontend directory" about the user who has authenticated? Even though the two components run in a common trusted environment, I don't want to pass the username (=joint, primary key) as the only information.

Which interfaces can be used between the directory and the legacy ID hub? Is this possible using SAML 2.0 or LDAP? I also need to account for the case that the directory authenticates the user through Kerberos.

Any advice would be appreciated!

MiKu

Answer (score 0):

You ask what interfaces can be used between the directory and the ID-hub. It depends on what protocols both have in common.

If you put a SAML IDP in front of the directory you can use SAML. Provided that your ID-hub supports SAML off course. In that case SAML can be one way to go. I its an industry standard for exchanging authorization information.